# iOS: Today Widget "unable to load" after reboot device

Tags: ios8-today-widget

After reboot device, if I directly visit today widgets, my app's today widget will show with "unable to load" (But if - after reboot device, firstly, I open my app, and then visit today widgets, everything works fine)

I tried my ways, but there is no way to debug this issue. I try to use "iOS Console", and get following error logs:

**key error logs:**

```
Sep 19 18:37:37 My-iPhone SpringBoard(Widgets)[58] <Notice>: <com.***.***: 0x109008200; container: WGWidgetListItemViewController> Remove snapshots at file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/3E4710C0-9E8F-4F87-B6DA-D7072057B92D/Library/Caches/com.apple.notificationcenter/Snapshots/com.***.***-PhoneTall-359-zh_CN-UICTContentSizeCategoryL-NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact.ca/ due to error: Error Domain=CAARFileLoadingDomain Code=950000 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1cc448f40 {Error Domain=CoreAnimationErrorDomain Code=2 "Unable to load CAPackage from URL: index.xml


Sep 19 18:37:39 My-iPhone SpringBoard(PlugInKit)[58] <Error>: Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.***.***" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.***.***}

Sep 19 13:36:16 My-iPhone backboardd(BaseBoard)[659] <Error>: Unable to bootstrap_look_up port with name com.xxxx.Extension.gsEvents: unknown error code (1102)

Sep 19 13:36:17 My-iPhone xxxxExtension(CoreFoundation)[996] <Error>: Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x1d411a940> (Domain: group.com.xxxx.extension-df, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: unfortunately, not yet.